# Wordpress: Advanced Custom Fields Plugin strips out <p> tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the ACF plugin (2.1.4 - latest version) for WordPress (3.2.1 - latest version).

Everything seems to work fine, except for when I use a WYSIWYG field. Any paragraph tags used are not saved to the database. TinyMCE is inserting them when I go to the HTML view, but as soon as I save and look in the DB tables, no paragraph tags are found.

This does not seem to affect other HTML like 'strong' tags etc however, interestingly enough, it does seem to affect 'br' tags as well.

When I save a page and look into the HTML view, they are all still there, but I think this is TinyMCE just doing its own formatting and not the 'literal' content as received from the database.

I reported this problem with an older version of the plugin a long while back which received little to no recognition at all. This is a totally new install of WP and the latest of the plugin so I assumed this bug would have been fixed by now - not so.

So now, instead of relying on them to sort it, I'm hoping for a quick / dirty / hack / fix for the meantime until this happens.

It's a great plugin, but this is a bit of a show stopper for me right now, and I assume others have had this problem too.

Many thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_field($field_id)` instead of `get_post_meta` will not strip the `p` tags.