# p tag being stripped from advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields

I am having the same problem that this user did, where the

tags are being stripped out from advanced custom fields when you enter them into the wysiyg editor.

[Wordpress: Advanced Custom Fields Plugin strips out <p> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672912/wordpress-advanced-custom-fields-plugin-strips-out-p-tags)

When you update using the advanced custom fields,it strips out all of the p tags on the custom fields... any reason why that is or how I can get around this issue?  Using the answer of that thread does not work, the issue is not bringing the actual custom fields onto the page template, but actually applying them to the custom fields since they get ripped out any time a user updates using the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: actually just solved this on my own, instead of using get_post_meta use:  

    <?php echo wpautop(get_field('your-custom-field')); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved it. If you were wondering why this happens, I'm thinking the plugin uses KSES to to strip out potentially malicious code.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

Unfortunately, it also removes most HTML tags unless you specifically allow them. Glad you figured out a workaround (a pretty simple and clever one, by the way).